# Ticketing system with PHP

Tags: php, email, architecture, service

I'm trying to make a ticketing system, but there are a few ways of doing it.

**Piping**

The problem with piping is trying to parse attachments and save them to a folder.

Here is a small script that I made

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php

//The concern here is having enough mem for emails with attachments.
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M'); 

ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$data = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])?file_get_contents('php://input'):file_get_contents('php://stdin');

$fdw = fopen("mail.txt", "w+");
fwrite($fdw, $data);
fclose($fdw);

?>
```

By using cPanel`s pipe to program.

It generates a raw email string, which contains alot of things that I don't understand. For example:

`--_1f366895-b327-4f84-8985-e3826cdf604b_
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="something.zip"
UEsFBBQACAAIAJuy1DgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKAAAAcmVwb3J0LnhtbNVdW5fbNpJ+n1/B9Z6zb8Mh
rgTPJplGt9N2HNvxiTPjM/vGltjdinUbUrLT+fVLUqJEUKSAYoE0p+10YkIdfwCBQl2+qvru73+s
lt6XJM0Dm/X3z4gfPPOyXbyex8vNOvn+2VOSPfv7D3/5y3dpst2kux++28V3y+SH72ab5X61zqr/
8NbxKv/0PN4Dz3747m+Hh43BWbzaxouHdecH4vlDutlvO8c/J09fN+m8e/zryyTb/SNddn5isdpm`

**Is there a way to parse them (img,docs,zip or etc) or put them in a folder/something.ext?**

**Is there another way to do this?**

External services?

**Is there already some service doing this?**

Comment: please do put in whats wrong with the question? thanks

Comment: What you are looking for (the key words to [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=php%20mime%20parser)) is a "PHP [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) parser". There are a few of them out there, I have used [this one](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3169-PHP-Decode-MIME-e-mail-messages.html) before and it did the job for me. It's not that complicated to parse MIME if you understand how it works, have a read of the Wikipedia article a referenced for starters, if you want to do this it would be good for you to get to grips with it a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get your output after the filename and then you decode your content with base64, because as you see in the header: `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`:

```
file_put_contents('something.zip', base64_decode($output));
```